# How to create a legend of both color and marker?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I want to show both color and marker in the legend. Colors mean one thing and markers mean another. It should look something like the attached image. This is the current code I have:

```
x = np.arange(20)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line1 = ax.scatter(x[:10],y[:10],20, c="red", picker=True, marker='*')
line2 = ax.scatter(x[10:20],y[10:20],20, c="red", picker=True, marker='^')

ia = lambda i: plt.annotate("Annotate {}".format(i), (x[i],y[i]), visible=False)
img_annotations = [ia(i) for i in range(len(x))] 

def show_ROI(event):
    for annot, line in zip([img_annotations[:10],img_annotations[10:20]], [line1, line2]):
        if line.contains(event)[0]:
            ...
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', show_ROI)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean two separate legends?

Comment: @DavidG, It can be one legend or two separate ones, but markers are not color specific. A marker can have different colors. And a color can have different markers.

Comment: Could you provide an example (preferably an image) of what the expected/desired outcome will be?

Comment: @DavidG I have added an image example of what I expected. Thanks!

Comment: As written in [link](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html), you can create various legend entries (Proxy artists). This might be what you want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following would be a generic example of how to use [proxy artists](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) to create a legend with different markers and colors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(8,10)
data[:,0] = np.arange(len(data))

markers=["*","^","o"]
colors = ["crimson", "purple", "gold"]


for i in range(data.shape[1]-1):
    plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,i+1], marker=markers[i%3], color=colors[i//3], ls="none")

f = lambda m,c: plt.plot([],[],marker=m, color=c, ls="none")[0]

handles = [f("s", colors[i]) for i in range(3)]
handles += [f(markers[i], "k") for i in range(3)]

labels = colors + ["star", "triangle", "circle"]

plt.legend(handles, labels, loc=3, framealpha=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to remove the markers for the colors and instead color the text? For instance, crimson, purple and gold in the legend would have no marker next to them and each string would instead be colored.